# How can you place a vector file inside a circle in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a display.newCircle() and I want to fill it with a vector image. I know how to do this with a 'png' file, but it doesn't work with vectors. I am using an 'svg' file and to import it I use:

```
  local nanosvg = require( "plugin.nanosvg" )
```

Comment: Load your image and render it with [`nanosvg.newTexture()`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/plugin/nanosvg/newTexture.html). Draw your circle with `display.newCircle()` and fill with a [BitmapPaint](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/ShapeObject/fill.html) by specifying the filename as seen in the example in the documentation for `nanosvg.newTexture()`. I haven't tried this, which is why it's a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this worked out to be the answer.

```
local nanosvg = require( "plugin.nanosvg" )

local tex = nanosvg.newTexture(
 { filename = "jelly.svg" })

image = display.newImage(tex.filename, tex.baseDir, display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY)
image.width = 100
image.height = 100
```